# Use MongoDB Allocation strategy effectively

Tags: mongodb, padding, allocation, mongodb-java

I am new to some of the MongoDB concepts like Allocation strategy. Currently I am using MongoDB-3.2.2 version, I am using the 
same version with Windows-32 bit and 64 bit as well. As per the Mongo documents the default allocation strategy is "PowerOf2Sizes"
 and which is better for insert/update/delete operations. I have the follwing requirement:
I am storing my logs into an array as one document. So Initially I started inserting one log into the array and then onwards I will update the
same array in the document with no.of log entries. So I am inserting and updating the array in the document.
Here I am using 32 bit (MMAPV1) and 64-bit(Wired Tiger) Engine.

As per my understanding from the Mongo documents, I do not need to set any padding factor(through Allocation strategy) to 64 bit to avoid document movement.
I only need to set padding factor(through allocation strategy) for 32 bit(MMAP v1 storage engine).

Could any body tell me how can I use Allocation strategy for my above requirement? Or Is my Understanding correct?

Comment: Please let me know If any details are missed then downvote, otherwise no body knows what is the problem in the query

Answer (score 0):

I have a very good video to answer your question. This is from MongoDb architect and will help you to analyse your requirement
https://youtu.be/9nYFnlM4vYw

Good Day

Answer (score 0):

In wiredTiger storage there is no padding required the storage is not linear as in MMapV1 where we get fragmentation problem due to movement of document to the end (or wherever the available empty space is).

If you already know that your document is going to be large enough and you don't want the movement, the allocation strategy is to insert your document having a field with large garbage text and then call an update with $unset  on that text field which will remove garbage text, that way your document already have got bigger space and movement of it is unlikely as the data grows further.

However there is a limit of 16MB per document which is good enough, so to maintain a healthy level, you can call $push with $slice as -50 (or so), this will make sure that your array have only last 50 logs.

If It is about logs, capped collection is a good strategy but then it will work when each log is a separate document which is not the case of your design.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am storing log entires in an array(one document) upto 10mb.There is a restriction from the application level to store upto
10 MB of log entries. but whenever creating the document, it will start insert with one log entry, after that It will update the same document
till it reaches 10MB. Do I need to set padding factor for this in case of MMAPV1 storage engine.

Comment: I have two answers for your scenario, if your log chunk size is small, it's better to set a definite padding factor, but it looks like you can set only 4 times the size of initial document, so if your initial document size is 3kb then a padding factor of 12 kb is useless when you know that it will grow to 10MB eventually. But initial insert document size is 800kb then 3200KB will definitely help in padding factor, more of it in here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/ZubUGYryFnI.

Comment: Now second is to not to worry about it, MMapV1 uses allocationOf2 size whenever it expands. which means, that if the space for the document is 2mb and your document crosses 2 mb it will be allocated 4mb and when it crosses 4mb it will be reallocated 8mb and so on, the catch here is once it crosses 8mb the allocated space will be 16mb whereas you would be using 10mb, so 6mb would be unused due to your application restrictions.

In conclusion I would say put a dummy string of size 1mb with a padding factor of 4.0 on collection and then unset that string, it will limit movement great deal

Comment: the link for setting padding factor is https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/

Comment: **I would say put a dummy string of size 1mb with a padding factor of 4.0 on collection and then unset that string**. Can you please give me an example if possible, It would be great if you provide me an example

Comment: ** if the space for the document is 2mb**, how this 2 MB will be decided. Please clarify

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB has a limit of 16MB/document. So your solution may not work in real time production serevers with good traffic. Beacuse the document will get exhausted when a prouction bug starts filling it quickly.

Below document will help you to design the back-end and bring scalability.

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-log-data/